# django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12704: character set mismatch

Tags: oracle12c, django-1.8

i faced a strange issue, trying to store a list of items (of length ~30) into database via `bulk_insert`, i get
`django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-12704: character set mismatch`
but inserting items one by one via `save` is OK, even putting a few items into `bulk_insert` works.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently. The sql django orm generated for bulk_create() is like this: 
Insert into table_name (column_name1, column_name2) select a1,a2 from dual union all select a3, a4 from dual.

Djano orm will convert all values into unicode before executing the statement. In cx_Oralce, None will be treated as VARCHAR2, unicode will be treated as NVARCHAR2, so if we will have ORA-12704 if a1 is None and a2 is not None. 
If we insert the items one by one, Django orm will use another sql so we won't have this problem.